# Delphi interface type incompatibility

Tags: delphi

What I am trying to do is to add common methods to these two classes which have the same indirect ancestor.

```
IMyMethods = interface
  procedure SomeMethod;
end;

TMyADODataset =class(TADODataset, IMyMethods) // ADO
public
  procedure SomeMethod;
end;

TMyUniDataset =class(TUniTable, IMyMethods) // UniDAC
public
  procedure SomeMethod;
end;
```

`SomeMethod` would be implemented differently for ADO and for UniDAC. So I thought an interface is perfect.

Then we have

```
TMyTable =class
private
  FDataset: TDataset;
end;
```

Here I have choosen TDataset as that is the common ancestor of TADODataset and TUniTable.

FDataset could be instantiated as follows:

```
if FProvider = prADO then
  FDataset := TMyADODataset.Create
else
  FDataset := TMyUniDataset.Create;
```

Now the problem is how to call `SomeMethod` of `FDataset`, the following does not compile and gives a type incompatibility error:

`IMyMethods(FDataset).SomeMethod;`

This is because `TDataset` does not implement `IMyMethods`, which is correct. But is there any way I can trick the compiler into accepting this? Or is there a better solution? I thought of class helpers but the implentation of `SomeMethod` will be different for ADO and UniDAC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`SysUtils.Supports()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Supports) function to obtain the `IMyMethods` interface from the `FDataset` object, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

var
  Intf: IMyMethods;
...
if Supports(FDataset, IMyMethods, Intf) then
  Intf.SomeMethod;
```

Just note that, in order for this to work, `IMyMethods` needs to have a Guid assigned to it, eg:

```
type
  IMyMethods = interface
    ['{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}']
    procedure SomeMethod;
  end;
```

You can generate a new Guid directly in the Code Editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+G</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea Supports existed, very useful.